# JSON parsing error, Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'

Tags: json

I try to find out why my JSON is not legal.
I use this site: http://jsonlint.com/

The first example which is good is:

```
{
        "data": 1290,
        "value": "a"
}
```

The second which is not good is:

```
{
    "data": 1290,
    "value": "a"
}
```

I dont understand why the second one does not work. Its the same as the first one.
[image]

EDIT

I found this sings at the end of the string. 
[image]

How to remove them using PHP? the string source is from php.

Comment: Check if there is no non-printable characters after end of your json.

Comment: Yea, I copied it to notepad and found some strange plush sings. How to remove them?

Comment: If processing in PHP, use `trim()` (other languages has similar functions). If done by hand: place marker before final `}` press delete till you don't see additional symbols, write `}` to compensate deleted one.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some additional output after you output your json. Try trimming output and terminating further execution.

```
$json = array('data' => 1290, 'value' => 'a');

echo json_encode($json);
die();
```